# Full Outer Join three tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following tables and desired output. I tried like full join based on value and group by subject but its still not showing the desired output [image]

Any help or guidance will be much appreciated. Below is the MySql query:

```
select t1.*,t2.value from Table1 as t1 left join Table2 as t2
on RIGHT(t2.value,1) =RIGHT(t1.value,1) 

union all 
select t1.*,t2.value from Table1 as t1 right join Table2 as t2
on RIGHT(t2.value,1) =RIGHT(t1.value,1)
```

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (`subject` varchar(30), `value` varchar(30));
CREATE TABLE Table2 (`subject` varchar(30), `value` varchar(30));
CREATE TABLE Table3 (`subject` varchar(30), `value` varchar(30));

INSERT INTO Table1
(`subject`, `value`)
VALUES
('subject1', 'ValueA1'),
('subject1', 'ValueA2'),
('subject1', 'ValueA3'),
('subject2', 'ValueA4'),
('subject2', 'ValueA5'),
('subject3', 'ValueA6'),
('subject3', 'ValueA7');

INSERT INTO Table2
(`subject`, `value`)
VALUES
('subject1', 'ValueB1'),
('subject1', 'ValueB2'),
('subject2', 'ValueB3'),
('subject1', 'ValueB4'),
('subject2', 'ValueB5'),
('subject3', 'ValueB6');

INSERT INTO Table3
(`subject`, `value`)
VALUES
('subject1', 'ValueC1'),
('subject2', 'ValueC2'),
('subject2', 'ValueC3'),
('subject2', 'ValueC4'),
('subject2', 'ValueC5'),
('subject3', 'ValueC6');
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant tables DDL + DML for sample data instead of that image, and remove the irrelevant tags. Just keep the tag of the RDBMS you are working with.

Comment: `RIGHT`  function comes from SQL-Server, it is not available on Oracle and MySlq, thus this query won't work on these databases, please remove irrelevant tags from the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `NOT EXISTS` along with the `UNION ALL`.

I think it's bit complicated with three tables, but here:

```
select *
from (
    select coalesce(t.subject, t3.subject) subject,
        t.value1,
        t.value2,
        t3.value value3
    from (
        select coalesce(t1.subject, t2.subject) subject,
            t1.value value1,
            t2.value value2
        from Table1 as t1
        left join Table2 as t2 on RIGHT(t2.value, 1) = RIGHT(t1.value, 1)
            and t1.subject = t2.subject

        union all

        select coalesce(t1.subject, t2.subject),
            t1.value,
            t2.value
        from Table1 as t1
        right join Table2 as t2 on RIGHT(t2.value, 1) = RIGHT(t1.value, 1)
            and t1.subject = t2.subject
        where not exists (
                select 1
                from table1 t
                where t.subject = t2.subject
                    and right(t.value, 1) = right(t2.value, 1)
                )
        ) t
    right join table3 t3 on t.subject = t3.subject
        and right(coalesce(t.value1, t.value2), 1) = right(t3.value, 1)

    union all

    select coalesce(t.subject, t3.subject) subject,
        t.value1,
        t.value2,
        t3.value value3
    from (
        select coalesce(t1.subject, t2.subject) subject,
            t1.value value1,
            t2.value value2
        from Table1 as t1
        left join Table2 as t2 on RIGHT(t2.value, 1) = RIGHT(t1.value, 1)
            and t1.subject = t2.subject

        union all

        select coalesce(t1.subject, t2.subject),
            t1.value,
            t2.value
        from Table1 as t1
        right join Table2 as t2 on RIGHT(t2.value, 1) = RIGHT(t1.value, 1)
            and t1.subject = t2.subject
        where not exists (
                select 1
                from table1 t
                where t.subject = t2.subject
                    and right(t.value, 1) = right(t2.value, 1)
                )
        ) t
    left join table3 t3 on t.subject = t3.subject
        and right(coalesce(t.value1, t.value2), 1) = right(t3.value, 1)
    where not exists (
            select 1
            from table3 t2
            where t2.subject = t.subject
                and right(t2.value, 1) = right(coalesce(t.value1, t.value2), 1)
            )
    ) t
order by subject,
    value1,
    value2,
    value3;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/HPPQRW19134)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to emulate a `full join` in MySQL is to select all the key values first and then use `left join`.  However, you are not looking for a `full join`.  That would produce a Cartesian product for each subject.

You want to "list" each subject independently in each column.  For that, you can use `union all`, `group by`, and variables:

```
select subject,
       max(value1) as value1,
       max(value2) as value2,
       max(value3) as value3
from ((select t1.subject, t1.value as value1, NULL as value2, NULL as value3
              (@rn1 := if(@s1 = subject, @rn1 + 1,
                          if(@s1 := subject, 1, 1)
                         )
              ) as rn
       from table1 t1 cross join
            (select @rn1 := 0, @s1 := '') params
      ) union all
      (select t2.subject, NULL, t2.value, NULL as value3
              (@rn2 := if(@s2 = subject, @rn2 + 1,
                          if(@s2 := subject, 1, 1)
                         )
              ) as rn
       from table2 t2 cross join
            (select @rn2 := 0, @s2 := '') params
      ) union all
      (select t3.subject, NULL as value1, NULL as value2, t3.value as value3
              (@rn3 := if(@s3 = subject, @rn3 + 1,
                          if(@s3 := subject, 1, 1)
                         )
              ) as rn
       from table3 t3 cross join
            (select @rn3 := 0, @s3 := '') params
      )
     )
group by subject, rn;
```